# wpf Richtextbox selected text distorted

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, wpf-controls

I am experimenting with the WPF RichTextBox and it shows some text in my application. I notice that When I select some text in that RichTextBox, the selected text gets distorted and the text below to that also gets distorted as shown below.

[image: RichTextBox Selected Text]

After I deselect that and scroll it comes back to normal.Is there anyway to avoid this distortion?

Comment: just a guess, but is anti-aliasing on?

Comment: also, try disabling hardware acceleration in screen settings and see if it makes any difference

Comment: I have tried disabling hardware acceleration in screen settings and it works fine. but how it can be done in client machine? or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I solved this problem by myself. I just added the following single line of code in my application and make it works. We need to disable hardware acceleration in screen settings using this.

**RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode = System.Windows.Interop.RenderMode.SoftwareOnly;**

[This](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/06/troubleshoot-grapics-rendering-issues.html) helped me a lot to fix my issue and it works for me.